# request.user not equal to name passed through url

Tags: django

I'm trying to limit a page so only the person whose page matches the URL can access it:

**urlconf**

```
url(r'^u/(?P<name>[-\w\d_]+)/edit/$', 'useraccounts.views.user_profile_edit')
```

**views.py**

```
def user_profile_edit(request, name):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user == name:
        username = User.objects.get(username=name)
        return render(request, 'useredit.html', {'user': username})
```

Printing out the contents of `print request.user` and `print name` upon page load to console shows the two are the same in my case (both are `root`). However, `print bool(request.user == name)` returns `False`, and as a result the view doesn't progress.

What is going on, and if applicable, is there a more elegant way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it wrong. `request.user` is an object, while `name` is a string.

Rewrite your condition as follows:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.username == name:
```

Comment: Checking only `if request.user.username == name` should be enough, as `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser` is supposed to implement the same interface as the `User` model and its `username` is a blank string `''`!